# Kafka-Connect-Hdfs - Couldn't start HdfsSinkConnector

Tags: hdfs, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I've downloaded kafka connect from http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/quickstart.html#quickstart

I'm trying to run the hdfs connector.
Here are the settings:

**connect-standalone.properties:**

```
bootstrap.servers=lvpi00658.s:9092,lvpi00659.s:9092,lvpi00660.s:9092

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter

internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
# Flush much faster than normal, which is useful for testing/debugging
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
 value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

and

**quickstart-hdfs.properties:**

```
name=hdfs-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=eightball-stuff11
hdfs.url=hdfs://localhost:9000
flush.size=3
```

I run the hdfs connector like this:
`cd /home/fclvappi005561/confluent-3.0.0/bin`
`./connect-standalone ../etc/kafka-connect-hdfs/connect-standalone.properties ../etc/kafka-connect-hdfs/quickstart-hdfs.properties`

but I get an error:

> [2016-09-12 17:19:28,039] INFO Couldn't start HdfsSinkConnector:
>   (io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkTask:72)
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied:
>   user=lvpi005561, access=WRITE,
>   inode="/topics":root:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:319)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:292)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:213)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:190)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1698)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1682)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkAncestorAccess(FSDirectory.java:1665)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.mkdirs(FSDirMkdirOp.java:71)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3900)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:978)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:622)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043) 
>           at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.(DataWriter.java:202)
>           at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkTask.start(HdfsSinkTask.java:64)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:207)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:139)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:140)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:175)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied:
>   user=fclvappi005561, access=WRITE,
>   inode="/topics":root:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:319)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:292)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:213)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:190)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1698)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1682)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkAncestorAccess(FSDirectory.java:1665)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.mkdirs(FSDirMkdirOp.java:71)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3900)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:978)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:622)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:2755)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:2724)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:870)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:866)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirsInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:866)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirs(DistributedFileSystem.java:859)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:1817)
>           at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.storage.HdfsStorage.mkdirs(HdfsStorage.java:61)
>           at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.createDir(DataWriter.java:369)
>           at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.(DataWriter.java:170)
>           ... 10 more Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException):
>   Permission denied: user=fclvappi005561, access=WRITE,
>   inode="/topics":root:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:319)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:292)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:213)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:190)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1698)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1682)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkAncestorAccess(FSDirectory.java:1665)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.mkdirs(FSDirMkdirOp.java:71)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3900)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:978)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:622)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1468)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:539)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:2753)
>           ... 20 more

I should mention that I run a docker image of hadoop locally at 127.0.0.1: `docker run -d -p 9000:9000 sequenceiq/hadoop-docker:2.7.1`

What is this permission denied error I'm seeing? I am on a different host that the ones mentioned under `bootstrap.servers`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The permission denied error is on the hdfs side. The user "root" doesn't have write access to the hdfs directory "/topics".